# How do I add a simple new route

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have been modifying module/Application/config/module.config.php and adding a new literal route like this...

```
    'routes' => array(

        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'categories' => array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/categories',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Categories',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
```

and further down adding the controller to the invokable array....

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        'Application\Controller\Categories' => 'Application\Controller\CategoriesController'
    ),
),
```

Yet when try to go to the url /categories I get a 404. The new Controller is valid, named correctly and placed in the correct folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does your `home` route work correctly?

Comment: I just reliased it was an AllowOveride issue. Ooops

Comment: :-) as always .. you keep staring yourself blind at the PHP stack.